# Automapper - Why isn't it mapping using SourceMember Attributes

Tags: c#, automapper

Why isn't Automapper mapping to Employee using SourceMember attributes? If I match name to name it works:

Doesn't work:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/yM9eiQ

Does work:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/GhpF9X

```
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.Configuration.Annotations;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AutoMapperConsole1
{
    [AutoMap(typeof(Person))]
    class Employee
    {
        [SourceMember("FirstName")]
        public string GivenName { get; set; }
        [SourceMember("LastName")]
        public string SurName { get; set; }
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //http://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting-started.html
            Person p = new Person();
            p.FirstName = "John";
            p.LastName = "Smith";

            //Create a map
            //Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Person, Employee>());
            //or
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Person, Employee>());

            //var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            //or
            var mapper = new Mapper(config);
            
            var dto = mapper.Map<Employee>(p);
            //or
            //Employee dto2 = Mapper.Map<Employee>(p);
            Console.Write(dto.GivenName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Attribute-mapping.html

Comment: Thank you, it looks like I needed ```AddMaps```. If you want to add that as an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute mapping relies on the assembly scanning done by `AddMaps`. For a given map, attribute mapping and `CreateMap` are exclusive. But you can have fluent maps and attribute maps in the same configuration.

Comment: So what you're saying here is that using `[SourceMember(nameof(Something))]` won't work without a fluent map? If that is the case, why even have the `SourceMember` decorator? Every path redirect I try with `SourceMember` isn't working.

Comment: No, check the tests in the repo for working examples.